# Java FXML need to reload a comboBox from another window

Tags: java, fxml, scenebuilder

(I am using Scene Builder) In my controller class I have a Combobox, when I open a new window and I fill the list inside the box with new items, when I close that window I need the combobox to change, but since it cannot be static I cant figure out a way.

Controller class for first window(revelant parts)

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    readCharacters();
    for (Character character : characterList) {
        System.out.println(character);
    }
    characterBox.setValue("Chars");
    characterList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Character::getPowerLevel).reversed());
    characterBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(characterList));


}
```

So when I press my New button this executes:
[image]

```
public void addNewWindow() throws IOException {

    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("newWindow.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This Opens from the above code
[image: This Opens from the above code]

Up until here all is well, when I press the Add button in the next window this executes from Controller2 class:

```
public void addNewCharacter() {

    if (addNameField.getText().equals("") || xField.getText().equals("") || pField.getText().equals("")) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Please fill all fields");

        alert.showAndWait();
    } else {
        Controller.characterList.add(new Character(addNameField.getText(), Double.parseDouble(xField.getText()), Double.parseDouble(pField.getText()), specialButton.isSelected()));
        Controller.writeCharacters(); //this writes the characterList to a file for when i reopen the programm
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I am done the comboBox on the original window won't have reloaded the new entry, I need to reopen the program for it to be updated with the new entry. So how do I solve this, apparently I can't make an FXML field static. So I can't figure out a way to send data to the ComboBox from Controller2 to Controller. I need a solution other than to make a reload button in the first window.

Answer (score 0):

Since loading the data into your ComboBox happens at initialization, I am not surprised that you find you have to reload the application to see the new entries. Here is one suggestion:

Start by creating a new method on the Controller for your first window. Make it public-access, with input parameters appropriate for updating your ComboBox, such as:

```
public void addItem(Character c)
{
   // add your logic here to update the ComboBox collection of items
}
```

Then from your second Controller, use the FXMLLoader to get a reference to the first one, something like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("YourFirstWindow.fxml"));
FirstControllerClass firstController = loader.getController();
```

And in the action event handler code, which must be your `addNewCharacter()` method, call the new method on your first Controller:

```
Character myNewCharacter = new Character(addNameField.getText(), Double.parseDouble(xField.getText()), Double.parseDouble(pField.getText()), specialButton.isSelected());
Controller.characterList.add(myNewCharacter);
Controller.writeCharacters();
firstController.addItem(myNewCharacter);
```